# REGEX: Extract latitude and longitude from Google Maps URL

Tags: regex

How can I extract the SECOND latitude and longitude from this string? (The latitude and longitude are the number after !3d (-15.7202756) and !4d (-47.8857498)

https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Abbraccio+Cucina+Italiana/@-15.7202756,-47.9207687,13z/data=!4m9!1m3!2m2!1srestaurants+in+Bras%C3%ADlia+-+Brasilia,+Federal+District!6e5!3m4!1s0x935a39a1395ec361:0x5c869291493e902c!8m2!3d-15.7202756!4d-47.8857498

`(-?[\d]*\.[\d]*),(-[\d]*\.[\d]*)` extracts the first values however, I need the SECOND latitude and longitude values.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2):

You might use

```
!3d(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)!4d(-?\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

To match 1+ digits you could use `+` instead of `*` or else a single dot would also match.

- `!3d` Match literally
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Match optional `-` digits with optional decimal part
- `!4d` Match literally
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+))` Match optional `-` digits with optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qf218i/1)

---

You could also use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), get the *path*, split on `/` and take the last part and get the values starting with `!3d` or `!4d` in capturing group 1 and 2.

```
$str = "https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Abbraccio+Cucina+Italiana/@-15.7202756,-47.9207687,13z/data=!4m9!1m3!2m2!1srestaurants+in+Bras%C3%ADlia+-+Brasilia,+Federal+District!6e5!3m4!1s0x935a39a1395ec361:0x5c869291493e902c!8m2!3d-15.7202756!4d-47.8857498";

$parts = explode('/', parse_url($str)["path"]);
$lastPart = end($parts);
preg_match("~!3d(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)!4d(-?\d+(?:\.\d+))~", $lastPart, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => !3d-15.7202756!4d-47.8857498
    [1] => -15.7202756
    [2] => -47.8857498
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex you could also just split the URL:

```py
lat, long = url.split("!3d")[1].split("!4d");

lat # '-15.7202756'
long # '-47.8857498'
```

(This is Python, but it would be similar in other languages)

Answer (score 0):

we can see latitude/longitude are numbers with precision 9 and scale 7.

you can use the following regex:

```
(\W?[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{7}).{3}(\W?[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{7})$
```

it grabs from the end of the string using the `$` operator. Is divided between two capture groups `(\W?[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{7})` which captures numbers with precision 9 and scale 7, i.e. 89.1234567 with a optional non-alphanumeric (i.e, "-" at the beginning)

we can see they are divided by 3 digits, so we can do `.{3}` between them. if you have cases with more or less digits diving them, you can use `.{1,x}` where x is a sufficient small number not for the regex to get from the latitude/longitude above.

if you are certain they will follow the rules you mentioned above, which is that they would follow !3d and !4d you can use the following regex to match the groups:

```
!3d(\W?[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{7})!4d(\W?[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{7})$
```